# Acrescentar '%' e formatar valor no campo text

Tags: jquery

Tenho um campo no formato `text`:

```
<input type="text" name="base_calculo" id="base_calculo">
```

Gostaria que, ao preencher este campo, acrescentasse o símbolo % no final dele e formatasse o campo dessa forma: 0.0%

Obrigado!

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o plugin [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)?

Comment: Não gostaria de usar um plugin, é este campo apenas... e ao ir preenchendo verá ficar 2.5% ou se só acrescentar o % no campo pelo jquery, ja estaria bom..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613642/mask-input-with-percent-sign

Answer (score 1):

A função não bloqueia apenas número nesse campo

```
$('#base_calculo').on('blur', function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    valor = valor.replace(',','.');

    if(!$.isNumeric(valor)) return;

    valor += '%';

    $(this).val(valor);

});
```

Comment: Não deu certo....

Comment: Só dá se eu clicar fora... gostaria que ao clicar no campo ele ja adicionasse então o % e conforme for preenchendo, colocasse o . certinho

Comment: Use a máscara money e na máscara coloquei decimal 1 e tem a opção la de colocar um caracter nao lembro bem